# Stop a method from further execution according the result of inner method call

Tags: c#, .net

The plot is this - I have a `Save()` method which calls a validation method withing itself and I want to be sure that if the validation method caught an error, the execution of the `Save()` method will be stopped. What I've done is making a `bool` method for the validation:

```
protected virtual bool IsNullOrEmptyControl(params Control[] controls)
        {
            bool validationFlag = false;
            foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ctrl.Text))
                {
                    ctrl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;                
                    if (validationFlag == false)
                    {
                        ctrl.Focus();
                        validationFlag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (validationFlag == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The fields in yellow could not be empty", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

And calling it from withing my `Save()` method:

```
public bool Save()
{
some code...
IsNullOrEmptyControl(txtClientCode, txtClientName);
some code..
clientService.Save(entity);
}
```

I thought that because my `IsNullOrEmptyControl()` method is `bool` if it returns `false` then this will mean stop of further code execution in `Save()` but it seems I was wrong. So what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsNullOrEmptyControl` method just returns the value.
You should check this value in our code and react to it

```
bool checkResult = IsNullOrEmptyControl(txtClientCode, txtClientName);
if(checkResult == false)
{
    return false;
}
some code..
clientService.Save(entity);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this is the most harmless way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code should be:

```
public bool Save()
{
  some code...
    if(IsNullOrEmptyControl(txtClientCode, txtClientName)) {  
      some code..
      clientService.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to leave the method call within the function, otherwise i will need to make a lot of changes. Isn't there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an if statementaround your save call. If the `IsNullOrEmptyControl` returns false the `clientService.Save(entity);` will not be executed.

```
public bool Save()
{
    //some code...
    if(IsNullOrEmptyControl(txtClientCode, txtClientName))
    {
        //some code..
        clientService.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be assigning the return value of your validation method to a variable and check it before calling `clientService.Save()`.

Also you may want to put a break in the `foreach` loop above, just below the line where you set your flag to `true`.

Comment: No, I want to mark all fields that don't match the validation rule with yellow, but I want the focus to stay on the first found. That's way I raise the flag but keep on checking.